# Roots of a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I need to find the 50 first roots of a transcendental equation.
I use Table and FindRoot, so I find repeated positives and negatives values in a list, but I want only the 50 first positives and differents roots.
Somebody can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using, in order that readers can assist you with it.

Answer (score 4):

For example, this is reasonably fast on the following example:

```
eqn = Sin[x] + 0.5 Cos[10 Pi x];

sols = FindRoot[eqn, {x, #}] & /@ Module[{n = 0},
  Reap[
    NDSolve[{y'[x] == D[eqn, x], y[0] == (eqn /. x -> 0),
      WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[x]; If[++n >= 50, "StopIntegration"]]},
     {}, {x, 0, Infinity}]
    ][[2, 1]]
  ]
(*  {{x -> 0.0534047}, {x -> 0.140935},..., {x -> 15.5391}}  *)

Plot[eqn, {x, 0, Max[x /. sols]}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[{x, 0} /. sols]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (# - 2)^2 (# + .5)^2 - 625/256 &[x], it seems that not all the roots can be found for this function.

Comment: @AlexanderZeng Use `NSolve` for polynomial equations.  (Why such a complicated example? It's pretty clear that any method that relies on sign change is going to fail on even-multiplicity roots, so `(x-2)^2` is sufficient.)  If you're looking for a similar approach for a transcendental equation, you might use `f[x] * f'[x]` and keep only those seeds for which `Abs[f[x]]` is small.