# Find simultaneous roots of Sin[x] and Cos[x] using FindRoot, If, and For

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

I am a beginner of *Mathematica*, I  happened to come across the following exercise which may seem trivial to the experts of this field but is hard for me to do at this level. I have the equation `Sin[x]=1/Sqrt[2]` where x lies between 0 and 10Pi, I want to find the the roots of this equation which also satisfy `Cos[x]=1/Sqrt[2]`. I am allowed  to use `FindRoot`, `If` statement and `For` loop for the problem. I apologize for the mistake in the original question which I edited by writing `1/Sqrt[2]` in place of Zero.

---

Can I proceed like

For i in the range 0 to 10Pi in increments of 0.1, 
 `FindRoot[Sin[x]=Cos[x],{x,i}]` and to check whether this is an actual root, I put it back in equation `Sin[x]=Cos[x]` using `If` statement and ask it to print the root for which `Sin[x]=Cos[x]`?

As I said, I am just learning *Mathematica*, so please bear with me if you find this improper.

Comment: I would appreciate other ways of solving this problem, if any, with or without the use of 'If', 'For' and 'FindRoot' commands.

Comment: You may have to look a long time to find a real number x where both Sin[x] and Cos[x] are zero. Why not plot the two functions and see...

Comment: Seems a little silly, but `Solve[Sin[x] == 0 && Cos[x] == 0 && 0 < x < 10 Pi, x]`. The answer, of course, is the empty set `{}`.

Comment: plot the two functions using `Plot[{
  Sin[x], Cos[x]
  },
 {x, 0, 10 Pi}
 ]`. Do you see any points in which they are both zero?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The exercise might had some mistake in it. I can see some points other than zero, where these curves do intersect.  Could you please tell give me some idea as to how to locate those points?

Comment: If you find those points wouldn't it mean that $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=0$ for them?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to use numeric root-finding for this problem; you can just do `Solve[{Sin[x] == Cos[x] == 1/Sqrt[2], 0 <= x <= 10 Pi}, x]` and get symbolic solutions.

Comment: Are you trying to find both places in the domain $[0, 10\pi]$ where $\sin x = 1/\sqrt{2}$. By the periodicity of $\sin$, when you find the one nearest zero, the other is just $2 \pi$  to the right.

Comment: Also, by simple math, when $\sin x = 1/\sqrt{2}$ so does $\cos x$. So you need not use Mathematica to verify it.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80317/4999

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to implement your idea:

```
dx = 10 Pi / 100;
sols = Table[
 Quiet[
  Check[
   FindRoot[
    Sin[x] == Cos[x],
    {x, x0, x0, x0 + dx}],
   Nothing,
   FindRoot::reged],
  FindRoot::reged],
 {x0, 0, 10 Pi - dx, dx}
 ]
```

You can convert the `Table` to [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) if you absolutely need to. See also [`AppendTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html) for building a list of solutions inside `For[]`.  Alternatively, you could build up the solutions with

```
sols = {sols, newsol};
```

inside the `For` loop; after the loop, use `sols = List /@ Flatten[sols]` to get it in standard multiple-solution form.  I will say that doing this task with `For` is more like using *Mathematica* to learn C or Java, and not like learning *Mathematica*.  See [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica) for more discussion of `For`.

I picked a `dx` that divides the interval evenly, instead of `0.1`.
I also used `Check` instead of `If`; see [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html), 
[`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html), 
[`FindRoot::reged`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/FindMinimum/reged). 
If you really want `If`, you might do something like the following instead of the `Quiet[..]` statement:

```
res = FindRoot[
  Sin[x] == Cos[x],
  {x, x0, x0, x0 + dx}];
If[Sin[x] == Cos[x] /. res,
 res,
 Nothing]
```

But again, `Quiet` and `Check` are the *Mathematica* tools designed for this sort of approach.

Check:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10 Pi},
 GridLines -> {x /. sols, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very  much Michael. It really worked for me. Just one query. I was going through *Mathematica* Documentation Center where I found FindRoot function with the form FindRoot[f, {x,xo}]   which specifies the initial point for the variable x, while as in your answer you have put an additional argument " x0 + 10 Pi/100". Could you please explain what this extra term does?.

Comment: @Jee There are three forms: `{x, x0}` which will use an unconstrained, damped, Newton's method (if the function is differentiable); `{x, x0, x1}` which will search without derivatives (e.g. secant method); and `{x, x0, x1, x2}` which still start at `x0`, constrain `x` to be within `x1 <= x <= x2`, and give the `reged` message if it tries to go outside the interval. My code constrains each search to be over the interval from `x0` to `x0 + dx` (I forgot to change the last `x0 + 10 Pi/100` to `x0 + dx`. (Using `dx` makes it easier to adjust the width of the intervals used; it can be made larger.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see that there are no solutions to Sin[x]=Cos[x]=0 by plotting:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

You can find the point (near 1) where Sin[x]=Cos[x] using:

```
FindRoot[Sin[x] == Cos[x], {x, 1}]
{x -> 0.785398}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one question. If I am not sure where the root lies, I have often found that FindRoot gives solutions (depending on initial point) which are not satisfying LHS=RHS. In that case, I would like to substitute the root obtained from FindRoot back into equation LHS=RHS and check for different initial values. Could you please help me to understand how to do this check for the actual root.

Answer (score 1):

Since your comment indicated that you are also interested in solutions other than using `FindRoot`

```
sol = Solve[{Sin[x] == Cos[x], 0 <= x <= 10 Pi}, x] // FullSimplify //
   SortBy[#, N] &

(*  {{x -> π/4}, {x -> (5 π)/4}, {x -> (9 π)/4}, {x -> (
   13 π)/4}, {x -> (17 π)/4}, {x -> (21 π)/4}, {x -> (
   25 π)/4}, {x -> (29 π)/4}, {x -> (33 π)/4}, {x -> (
   37 π)/4}}  *)
```

Verifying

```
And @@ (Sin[x] == Cos[x] /. sol)

(*  True  *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
sol // N

(*  {{x -> 0.785398}, {x -> 3.92699}, {x -> 7.06858}, {x -> 
   10.2102}, {x -> 13.3518}, {x -> 16.4934}, {x -> 19.635}, {x -> 
   22.7765}, {x -> 25.9181}, {x -> 29.0597}}  *)
```

You could also use `NSolve` or `Reduce`